# SharePoint 2013 - Relevant Conversions in HashTagProfile don't show up if Hashtag is used in mysite

Tags: 2013, search, mysite, tagging

If somebody uses a Social Tag in a posting on a community site, this entry also shows up in the relevant conversations of the corresponding `HashTagProfile.aspx`. However if the posting is made on the mysite newsfeed the entry doesn't show up.

I found out that the link on these entries are different.
Entries from the mysite URL look like `https://<domain>/ThreadView.apsx?ThreadID=<longID>` (examle for `<longID>` --> `1.9a8f5e11248243718bd327f2dadac129.4c98ec3e48864268be2bdf243b5c59f8.a2e19c39b0df46a7baeb6cae678137ff.0c37852b34d0418e91c62ac25af4be5b.98a0e90156f34889acf63313da305ba2.68.68.S-1-5-21-3312761167-2807315300-1982944300-36524`),
whereas entries from communities look e.g. like `https://<domain>/site/<sitename>/newsfeed.apsx?ThreadID=https://<domain>/site/<sitename>/Lists/PublishedFeed/DispForm.aspx?ID=<ID>`

I also checked the newsfeed setting in the profile on the mysite. Under "Activities I want to share in my newsfeed" i checked the box "Share all of them".

In the Search Crawl Logs i found some interesting entries...
`sts4s://mysite.<domain>/siteurl=personal/<user>/siteid={7df8e83b-4c0a-4951-a1b6-2cd926a1b54f}/weburl=/webid={b78a70f2-ff88-4e99-b390-0d1f4b5cb046}/listid={c2cfa518-6e29-4511-a02e-9319adb7efda}/folderurl=Private/Microblogging?ID=6`
`SharePoint list is corrupted. The list item doesn't have a display URL. (SearchID = 8D3ACB8B-7EBB-4461-B829-72E0609D3E16)`

...which corresponds to following log entry in the SharePoint logs:
`CSTS3Accessor::Init: GetDisplayURL returns empty string for URL sts4s://mysite.<domain>/siteurl=personal/<user>/siteid={7df8e83b-4c0a-4951-a1b6-2cd926a1b54f}/weburl=/webid={b78a70f2-ff88-4e99-b390-0d1f4b5cb046}/listid={c2cfa518-6e29-4511-a02e-9319adb7efda}/folderurl=Private/Microblogging/itemid=6  [sts3acc.cxx:437]  search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx`

Via SharePoint Manager I examined the corresponding list which is called "Soziales Netzwerk" because the Mysite is german (english name would probably be "Social network").
There is an entry for every community and team site in which the user is active. Only the entry for ContentType="Mikroblogeigenschaften" (english name would probably be: "Microblog Properties" doesn't show an URL, which would explain the above mentioned error. This message also appears for Followed Sites as well as for followed Documents. But still, I have no clue, if this could have an effect for my problem or perhaps is a "works as designed" behaviour.

Also in the Search Crawl Logs there is a success message which says "Crawled" for the link `https://mysite.<domain>/personal/<user>/Social/Private/Microblogging` which should correspond to the user postings, but I'm not 100% sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we found out that the problem was in our configuration. We set the Microfeed List in the mysite to hidden as we thought the appearance of this list could be confusing for the the users, because the content of this list are two folders with GUIDs which contain information of the user postings, but in a very technical way.

The problem is, that hidden Lists aren't crawled and therefore the linking of Hashtags to the relevant conversations didn't show up.
(as posted here: [Search not indexing custom lists](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34791/search-not-indexing-custom-lists))

If you can't find success messages "Crawled" in the Search Crawl Log for items with the following URL `https://mysite.<domain>/personal/<users>/Lists/PublishedFeed/*` you probably have the same problem.